# CSS move overflowing content to adjacent column

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to move vertical overflowing content to a separate column.

EG.

We have two `divs`.

```
<div class="col-1">
   Overflowing content
</div> 
<div class="col-2">
  Move overflowed content into here
</div>
```

Is this possible

I tried to find if it possible and could not

Comment: There was a proposal to add this ability to css some time ago but it was abandoned as I recall.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, I thought I'd seen it somewhere.  Something like flow into.